# Получение координат с бд mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

Как заносить координаты из бд mysql в google карты?Я сделал как по документации, карту вывело. Но мне нужно выводить координаты определенного поста в карту. Ето, через foreach перебирать и в json или как вобще. Первый раз делаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1: полная статика.
Просто берёте в цикле и генерите на php сразу все точки с координатами прямо в контент страницы:

```
<script>...
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: {'lat':1, 'long':1}});
<?php
$template = "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: %s, lng: %s}, map: map, title: '%s'});";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
       printf ($template, $row['lat'], $row['long'],$row['title']);
    }
    $result->close();
}
?>
} 
</script>
```

Вариант 2: динамическая загрузка.
JS со статической страницы подгружает через AJAX список координат в JSON, в итоге код серверного фрагмента будет еще проще, но вот со стороны JS потребуется дополнительно обрабатывать данные и динамически их добавлять к перечню объектов:

```
<?php
$response = array();  
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {  
       $response[] = array('lat'=> $row['lat'], 'long'=>$row['long'], 'title'=>$row['title']);  
    }  
    $result->close();  
}
echo json_encode($response);  
?>
```